# Failed pvc attachment using kubernetes longhorn

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running a self hosted RKE2 (rancher) kubernetes cluster (1.27) and longhorn (1.4.2) and I need some help for the correct configuration.
I'm deploying some database stuff via helm, like mongoDB, redis, postgres and minio. Every database ca be deployed by it's own without a problem. But if I try to run every helm chart, randomly some deployment fail with an attachement error of the PVC:

```
AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "pvc-0b5bd219-b009-4877-96dd-3c0e7549533d" : rpc error: code = Aborted desc = volume pvc-0b5bd219-b009-4877-96dd-3c0e7549533d is not ready for workloads
```

The PVC is existing and bound. And after removing every helm deployment and doing it again it works and another database has the same error.

I didn't have any specific configuration and maybe this is the problem:

**values.yaml**

```
persistence:
  defaultFsType: xfs
```